# Jenkins/Groovy - Access all workspaces for a job with concurrent builds

Tags: jenkins, concurrency, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job that runs concurrently on multiple slave nodes i.e. there are multiple workspace directories for this job - `/home/jenkins/workspace/jobA`, `/home/jenkins/workspace/jobA@2`, `/home/jenkins/workspace/jobA@3` etc.

I have been looking at this script which lets you clean up workspaces for a list of jobs on all the nodes - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Wipe+workspaces+for+a+set+of+jobs+on+all+nodes. However, upon testing, I realized that this only removed the directory `/home/jenkins/workspace/jobA` and did not catch those ending with `@`.

The script retrieves the workspace path via `workspacePath = node.getWorkspaceFor(item)`. I have searched online to find an equivalent of this function to instead fetch a list of **all** workspace paths for a concurrent job but did not really find any info.. Not sure if I was looking in the wrong places or missed something.

Any help/pointers in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such API currently; you would need to look for sibling folders ending in `WorkspaceList.COMBINATOR` plus a number.